# How to save attributes from extended datastore classes within another class

Tags: datasource, wakanda

I'm using Wakanda platform and I am developing a web based application that schedules trips for a non emergency transportation company as a project.

I have created datastore classes for some job positions, patients and vehicles. 
I have created a form for the schedule that contains attributes from extended classes. In order to get those values I have created alias attributes withing the schedule class.

My issue is that when i'm filling the form, those values don't get save. I have also added a grid next to my form and despite the fact that I can create a single trip the values don't get save though.Also when I tried to export that class the only values that exported are those that belong to that class and are not form extended.

Any ideas?

AUTOFORM-GRID-MODEL SCREENSHOT:
[image: AUTOFORM-GRID-MODEL SCREENSHOT]

EXAMPLE ALIAS SCREENSHOT:
[image: EXAMPLE ALIAS SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 1):

Alias attributes are just references to available attributes, so they allows you to only display attributes from related DataClasses. You can't use them to create new entities ( for instance : create a Patient entity by simply affecting a value to patient.name based alias attribute ).

Please refer to : [Attribute Categories](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/Attributes.300-574626.en.html-574643)  for more informations about attribute categories.

Try using an "Auto Form" instead, and when you are filling the form, try to search for the retated entity by using the Autocomplete property in the Data Model Editor.

Try to do the same as the example in the end of the this link : [Publishing an Auto Form](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Prototyper/Prototyper-Widgets/Auto-Form.300-307049.en.html).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply!

I have tried to use an auto form and the auto complete property. It works but each of the values that I need comes from a different source (relational attribute) that is created (patient0.lastName) when I'm dragging the attribute of the relation that I want from the basic class. Moreover to the grid I can assign only one source and i have assigned the basic class to it!

Comment: I have also tried to add into the autoform values with sources from the basic class (mission.patient.lastame) and also assign to them the auto compete property but instead of the last names of the patients only a value"true" is shown inside the text input.. I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

To make the grid work the way you want (allow you to update data in related ds classes), you could use a [calculated attribute](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/Attributes.200-715321.en.html-715386).  In the onGet event you would just get the info from the related entity.  In the onSet event you would load the related entity, set the attribute and save.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Inside the mission (basic) table I have 4 N-> 1 relations that are connected with other tables (patients, drivers...). Do I have to create new entities inside my basic class and make them calculated to get the values from the related entities?(I need to get values coming form the related classes) Because calculated attributes cannot be applied to relational attributes and as they don't store information will that work in order to show the needed values inside a combo box or Textinput with autocompete propery?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I'm following you.  But if your model has a relation like this:  Mission.driver and Driver.missions.  If you are displaying a mission entity and displaying the name of the N -> 1 driver.  Then you could create a calculated attribute Mission.driverName.  And the code onGet would query to find the N -> 1 driver and return driver.name.  And the onSet code would query to find the N -> 1 driver, set driver.name and save the driver entity.

Comment: Im going to try this thanks! Isn't possible to get the values directly with a source like mission.drives(related attribute).lastName ? When I tried this with related attributes entities within a form widget the output was just one value "true" instead of the values that I have  added for lastNames..

Comment: In order to get the values (calculated attribute) from the related entities, is something like that suppose to work? 
model.Mission.mDriver.onGet = function() 
{ return this.driver.lastName; }; 
How can I refer to an entity from a related attribute (N->1 driver) in order to return the  "lastName"value?
I have also add some screenshots regarding my model if that helps!

Comment: Your code looks correct, this.driver.lastName should work.

Comment: It doesn't working.. It doesn't get the values from the relation attributes and I need that in order to create the a grid for the mission table with all the other values from the other tables!I've been trying to do this for a week but I cant find out how!! do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you haven't already, I would create a new blank solution and try setting up a calculated attribute just to make sure you can get it working properly.  Don't try anything client side at first, just try to create a calculated attribute and access it server side.  Calculated attributes definitely work, but everything has to be setup just right.  Also, make sure you test your calculated attribute code server side on its own...  ds.Mission.all()[0].driver.lastName should work or something else is wrong.  Long story short, make sure everything is working on the server before moving to client.

Comment: I've tried that already yes! I created 3 tables as the other post below and I tried to access the extended values but it doesn't work(also on another computer)..I'm using calculated attributes in some tables for values that are within the same class and its working.. (fullname-name +surnme)
I have just tested the calculated attributes on server side but its not working neither..When Im typing the code wakanda shows me the choices that I have (classes, attributes) and shows me all that I need except of the last value which is the extended..which means that for some reasons it cant access them.

Comment: I have tried to access this value both from the calculated attribute and the relation one but it doest show me as a choice the value that I need (attribute from extended class).. Also I haven't found anything similar in the wakanda documentation in order to access related values.. Do you have any ideas? have you tried something like that and its working? can you send me a sample of that code or something? really appreciate you time.. thank you

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with extended classes.  I always recommend against that approach, always seems to cause more trouble than it is worth.  Try sticking with just normal datastore classes and calculated attributes will definitely work.  Sounds like you may have found a bug with extended classes which wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: No worries, thank you!
I hope that it isn't a bug and there is a way to achieve that as I have 2-3 weeks to complete my project!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Grid to display mission details, in the 'properties' tab of the grid, go to 'Columns' and add attributes that you need ( for example add mDriver attribute with drivers.name as a value ).

[image]

By doing this you can display and detete missions but you can't add missions with related attributes.

In order to achieve that use an Auto form, it allows you to add, update missions.

[image]

I have tried this and it works, here is the model that i have used :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Despite the fact that I want to use autocompete property(autoforms don't support autocompete property) or combo boxes in order to chose which values to assign to each mission I have tried this method but it doesn't work.. The only values that are updated to the grid are those that are not extended as you can see to the images that I have attached! Also in both autoform and grid I have assigned only the entities that I wanted to be shown from each attribute (both from mission) instead of the whole table! It's weird that the other values don't updated though..

Comment: I have also added a screenshot (hope the helps)with a form that I have created and it is an example of what I want to finally achieve! I achieved that by assigning the alias attributes to the combo boxes.. I tried to add the values form the datasources instead of the alias attributes in order for the values to get saved but neither the combo boxes functioning as expected nor the grid!